# Parse JSON data to AS3 and show it in flash text field

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

First of all, I'm not a programmer, but a graphic designer and it is really hard for me to solve this on my own.

What I need is to get the **estimatedJackpotLC** which is in **"lotteryId":"3"** from this URL https://api.lottotech.com/api/v1/345/UpcommingDraws and parse it into a dynamic text field in Flash Pro CC. I am using AS3 and Flash Player 11 (which I heard support JSON parsing natively?). How to do that? I would really appreciate some help.

Here is the JSON data:

```
{   "totalCount": 0,
"items": [{
    "lotteryId": 3,
    "drawId": 303,
    "estimatedJackpotLC": 60000000.0,
    "endsOn": "2014-12-10T22:00:00Z"
},
{
    "lotteryId": 2,
    "drawId": 326,
    "estimatedJackpotLC": 10000000.0,
    "endsOn": "2014-12-12T13:00:00Z"
},
{
    "lotteryId": 1,
    "drawId": 331,
    "estimatedJackpotLC": 31000000.0,
    "endsOn": "2014-12-12T14:00:00Z"
},
{
    "lotteryId": 4,
    "drawId": 336,
    "estimatedJackpotLC": 102000000.0,
    "endsOn": "2014-12-12T22:00:00Z"
},
{
    "lotteryId": 5,
    "drawId": 367,
    "estimatedJackpotLC": 14400000.0,
    "endsOn": "2014-12-11T15:00:00Z"
},
{
    "lotteryId": 7,
    "drawId": 387,
    "estimatedJackpotLC": 12200000.0,
    "endsOn": "2014-12-14T16:30:00Z"
}]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be better to paste a sample of what you're trying to parse into the question directly -- that URL is unreachable for me and also looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: Hello there, I've edited my question with the json data in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the bare-bones code for what you're looking to do, comments included:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.globalization.CurrencyFormatter;

// create currency formatter
var cf:CurrencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter(LocaleID.DEFAULT);
cf.groupingSeparator = " "; // set the grouping separator to space
cf.fractionalDigits = 0; // don't show any decimal places

// creating a text field, you probably already have one on your display list
var dynamicTextField:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(dynamicTextField);

// load the JSON data from the URL
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("https://api.lottotech.com/api/v1/345/UpcommingDraws"));
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);

// handle the load completion
function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    var result:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data); // parse the JSON data
    var items:Array = result.items; // retrieve the items array

    // loop over all the items...
    for each(var item:Object in items)
    {
        // ... until you find the one you're looking for
        if(item.lotteryId == 3) 
        {
            // set the text, using the currency formatter
            dynamicTextField.text = cf.format(item.estimatedJackpotLC, true); // true tells it to use the currency symbol 
            break; // break out of the loop b/c you found the item you're looking for
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, you are the best, Marcela! I've managed to put the result in a textfield, that I created, so I can edit things like color and animation, but is it possible to format the result to look something like "$60 000 000" instead of just "60000000"? Thanks again, you helped me alot already!

Comment: I've updated the code to show you how to use AS3's native `CurrencyFormatter`

Comment: Thanks alot again, Marcela. The code worked flawlessly for me!

Comment: For some reason it works in the flash preview (ctrl+enter), but when I open the .swf file it does not show anything. I tried uploading it to a remote sever and opening it, still the same. Tried publishing it with HTML, not working. Tried few things with the code, nah, not working. I even created a blank file with the code only, and yeah it is the same - working only in the preview. Very frustrating. Looks like some security measures or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the spam, but if i make `new URLRequest("UpcommingDraws.txt")` and create a local .txt file it is working fine. But it doesn't when JSON is loaded remotely.

Comment: It does appear that you're running into some security sandbox issues. The best I can offer is to add some more event listeners to the urlLoader to see where it's failing.

Comment: I have tried tons of variants to try to fix this, nothing really helped. Everything works with ctrl + enter preview, but once I open the file it shows nothing. Google can't find anything about the topic,  it is really strange that no one ran into that issue. Is there an alternative option to load the data from URL?

Comment: Google does have a lot of hits on this issue: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS549US549&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=urlloader%20not%20working%20browser

Comment: Debug Errors:

`Warning: Failed to load policy file from https://.../crossdomain.xml
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to https://.../UpcommingDraws halted - not permitted from file:///.../preview.swf
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file:///.../preview.swf cannot load data from https://.../UpcommingDraws.
[preview_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:19]
Error: Request for resource at https://.../UpcommingDraws by requestor from file:///.../preview.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.`

Is it a remote server problem?

Comment: Looks like a cross-domain issue. If you don't have access to the server hosting the UpcomingDraws, you can _try_ changing the playback security settings. In publish settings, select "access network only" for local playback security (http://i.gyazo.com/e54e7b8fe8606ea915e17abc195f351d.png). I can't guarantee that this will solve your issue, as a crossdomain file may be required on the server: http://www.ookla.com/support/a21097566/What-is-crossdomain-xml-and-why-do-I-need-it

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried your suggestion yesterday, and it doesn't help. I wrote an email to the site owners, as I am almost 100% sure that the problem in on their part. I am waiting for a response from them. Anyways, thanks for your assistance.